# Is Sahu Sajda required when Imam recites incorrectly?

Tags: quran-recitation, mistake

What should the Imaam do when he mistakes during his qira'at?

Mistakes such as

1. Jump to the next verse.
2. Miss one or several words
3. Pronounce incorrectly.
4. Repeat an ayah for several times.

If the Imaam stops his qira'at and someone gives *luqma* does it make *sahwu sajda* mandatory [*Wajib*].

Answer (score 1):

The Sajda Sahuw is only requried when an Imam:

1. Forgets a mandatory [Faraz]. For example, forgets 1 Sajda, or forgets number of Rakat, forgets Raku, forgets Qeyam (standing), or skips by mistake next Faraz.
2. Read Tash-had till or beyond Darood in 2nd Rakat (while sitting) while being in 4 Rakat Faraz, where Imam is supposed to get up for 3rd Raqat.
3. Imam is was supposed to sit for Tash-had but he stands up.

This is mentioned in Quran to offer Sajda-Sahaw when any Faraz gets missed.

Repeating any Ayah or forgetting any Ayah or any Luqma in Salat/Prayer/Namaz does not required any Sajda-Sahaw. For instance, if you see Namaz-e-Taraveeh in Ramadan. In Namaz-e-Taraveeh Imam recites and if forgets something there is a special dedicated person behind Imam to feed or give Luqma of correction and no Sajda-Sahaw is conducted at the end.

In Jamaat/collective prayer behind Imam this does not apply to followers. This only apply to single person when he/she is offering Prayer/Salat/Namaz as single.

Also, In some cases if you gone late and you missed 1 Rakat, you required to stand (to complete your missed 1 Rakat) after Imam says `Asalam-o-alaikum Wa Rehmatullah`. In that case now you are offerign Prayer/Salat/Namaz as a single; so now if you do any mistake as mentioned above then you have to do Sajda-Sahaw. 
Moreover, if you by mistake followed Imam `(on Aslam-o-Alaikum Wa Rehmatullah)` and moved your head by mistake, and suddenly you noticed that you missed 1 Rakat, and you need to complete that too, then you required to offer 1 Sajda-Sahaw at end of your prayer.

Comment: This answer needs evidences to support your claims (see [answer])

Answer (score 0):

In case of reading quran in the praying as you mentioned, there is no need for sahwu sajda.

However, the exception is if it's done while reading Al-Fatiha (The first soura read in the beginning of the praying). Then it must be corrected. If it's not corrected, you will need to re-pray this raka'a since Al-Fatiha is mandatory (roukn) which is more than wajib and praying is not correct if it's not. Of course this all assuming the mistake is noted and not forgotten so it can be corrected or remembered later before the pray end.

Here are the links for such situations Fatwa

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLKGTJbsHrQ

http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=16592